# not able to loop through all sheets

Tags: vba, excel, loops

VBA beginner here,
I'm trying to loop following code through all sheets.
But whenever I try to run it, It gets executed only for the current active sheet.

```
 Sub test1()

 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim k As Integer

     For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

         For i = 1 To Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
             For k = Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row To 3 Step -1

             Cells(k - 1, i) = Cells(k - 1, i) & ", " & Cells(k, i)

             Cells(k, i).Clear
             Next k

         Next i

     Next ws

 End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't written any of this in a long time and don't remember the API much, but it's very curious that you loop through `Sheets`, assigning each to `ws` but never actually reference `ws` after that. I assume that there is some property of `ws` that will be helpful to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to prefix `Cells` with your worksheet object like `ws.Cells`. Below is a working version of your code. Give it a try.

```
Sub test1()

 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim k As Integer

     For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

         For i = 1 To ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
             For k = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row To 3 Step -1

             ws.Cells(k - 1, i) = ws.Cells(k - 1, i) & ", " & ws.Cells(k, i)

             ws.Cells(k, i).Clear
             Next k

         Next i

     Next ws

 End Sub
```

Comment: Or use `With...End With` construction to avoid repeating `ws` variable